# My access database does not update (ASP.NET)

Tags: c#, asp.net, database, visual-studio, ms-access

I think I have trouble connecting to my database because it does not update when it's supposed to. I'm not sure as to why this is. 
Here's my .aspx.cs file:

```
public partial class addClass : System.Web.UI.Page
{
    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

    }

    private static OleDbConnection GetConnection()
    {
        String connection;
        connection = @"connectionstring";

        return new OleDbConnection(connection);

    }
    string one = "one";
    protected void submitButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        OleDbConnection myConnection = GetConnection();


        try
        {

            myConnection.Open();
            String myQuery = "INSERT INTO Yoga Class([ClassName], [Level], [Duration], [Capacity], [Description]) values ('" +
                classNameTextBox.Text + "','" + levelDropDownList.SelectedItem.Text + "','" + durationDropDownList.SelectedItem.Text + "','" + capacityDropDownList.SelectedItem.Text +
                "','" + descriptionTextBox.Text + "');";

            String myQuery2 = "INSERT INTO YogaTeacher([TeacherID]) values('" +one+ "');";


            OleDbCommand myCommand = new OleDbCommand(myQuery, myConnection); //get rid of parameters 



            myCommand.ExecuteNonQuery();

            myConnection.Close();
        }

        catch
        {
            Response.Write("Form did not submit due to an error");
        }

        finally
        {
            myConnection.Close();
        }
    }



   }
}
```

I think the reason it is not updating is because the column teacherID in the table 'Yoga Class' is a foreign  key from another table. The error message in the 'catch' statement displays when I click the submit button. Am I correct? And if  am how do I change my code to make it work?

Any help appreciated

Thank You

Comment: Mind me asking why you are using Microsoft Access?  I haven't seen someone use an access database for data storage on an app in a decade, it's generally not considered a good idea to do.  Unless it's for work and a work requirement you have no control of.  Better choices include SQLite, Sql Server Express, Sql Server Compact Edition, PostGreSQL, MySql, or even nosql stuff like MongoDB.  Or maybe it's for a college class, and I really hope college classes aren't still teaching Microsoft Access databases in C# classes.

Comment: This code is crazy-vulnerable to sql injection. It's practically begging to get hacked.

Comment: this is only for a college project but I appreciate the advice

Answer (score 1):

Your code:
String myQuery = "INSERT INTO *Yoga Class*...
The tablename "Yoga Class" shouldn't have a space in it.

Comment: well spotted but that didn't fix the problem

Answer (score 0):

Your connection string is invalid.  You have it set to the string "connectionstring" and it should be a full formated proper Connection String: such as

```
"Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source=C:\myFolder\myAccessFile.accdb;
Persist Security Info=False;"
```

Comment: It's a sample connection string. On my real file I've got the proper file path.

Comment: It's probabl UAC.  It's an access database file, if it requires elevated permissions then your process doing this would need to run as administrator to open it.

Grant the process/users running your app access to the file.

Run visual studio as administrator, then open your project and see if it works to test that theory.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion but it did not work. This is frustrating.